# Extracting zip file with php stream gives a "false positive" CRC error

Tags: php, zip

I'm getting a "false positive" E_WARNING `file_get_contents(): Zip stream error: CRC error`
with the following code on Debian:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('zip' => array('password' => '1234567890')));
$string = file_get_contents('zip://test.zip#test.csv', false, $context);
```

but the extracted data is ok, no crc error.

Comment: Can we test your Zip file?

Comment: @Zerte here is the file https://filebin.net/ln9c117awst7udzs/test.zip?t=6nvxmq7z

Comment: 7-Zip and WinZip see no problem with that Zip file. The file is AES-encrypted. I suspect a bug in the CRC calculation of the extractor.

Comment: i've come to the same conclusion, oddly i found no way to disable the "bugged" crc check, the only (bad) way is to suppress the error with @